# wlstModule connection information lost

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g, wlst

When using wlst with a WebLogic 10.3.5.0 release I am puzzled by the following situation and hoping for an answer.

Given a standard wlst command to connect to a server

```
connect('weblogic','welcome1','t3s://localhost:7002')
```

it connects as expected to the AdminServer in my domain and presents the following prompt:

```
Connecting to t3s://localhost:7004 with userid weblogic ...
Successfully connected to Admin Server 'AdminServer' that belongs to domain 'base_domain'.

wls:/base_domain/serverConfig>
```

However, if I perform the following command

```
import wlstModule as wlst
wlst.connect('weblogic','welcome1','t3s://localhost:7002')
```

I get the following response

```
Successfully connected to Admin Server 'AdminServer' that belongs to domain 'base_domain'.

wls:/offline>
```

The situation I have is I have a common module for connecting the AdminServer and whilst the connection is successful, any other functions revolving around requiring  a serverRuntimeConfig(), etc, do not work as it thinks it is not connected.

Does anybody have any idea on the correct mechanism for using the second approach for connecting and what else needs to occur to retain the connection state when using the imported wlstModule.

Comment: if you have found a solution for this, I would like to hear it. having the same problem here.

Comment: try starting java org.python.util.jython and do the import that way..

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this very problem, I seem to have found the answer.

after you start with java org.python.util.jython, you get a prompt.

>>>

here you can do

`import wlstModule as wlst`

hencefort you should use the wlst all the time!!

`wlst.connect()`

`a = wlst.cmo.getServers()`

`print (a)`

greetings,

Saulius

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that option.  You will note it is used in the example above.  It does not solve why it still thinks it is offline.

Comment: as far as I can see, you start wlst and not jython. if you import wlst for use with java weblogic.WLST, I haven't gotten it to work i'm afraid, not interactively in any case.